# Request big file stream failed with wcf rest

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, streaming, httpwebrequest

I have a REST GET API that is written using WCF library to return Stream of a specific requested file that is located on API server that hosts that web service application. The service works well if the size of the requested file is small; that is less than 100 MB.  But if file size is greater than > 100 MB, then the service returns 0 bytes without any logged information I can get the library method (saying, the "catch" block).

The library method (the class library project) returns Stream of needed file is

```
public Stream GetFile(string fileId, string seekStartPosition=null)
        {
            _lastActionResult = string.Empty;
            Stream fileStream = null;

            try
            {
            Guid fileGuid;
            if (Guid.TryParse(fileId, out fileGuid) == false)
            {
                _lastActionResult = string.Format(ErrorMessage.FileIdInvalidT, fileId);
            }
            else
            {
                ContentPackageItemService contentItemService = new ContentPackageItemService();
                string filePath = DALCacheHelper.GetFilePath(fileId);

                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

                    long seekStart = 0;
                    // if seek position is specified, move the stream pointer to that location
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(seekStartPosition) == false && long.TryParse(seekStartPosition, out seekStart))
                    {
                        // make sure seek position is smaller than file size
                        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
                        if (seekStart >= 0 && seekStart < fi.Length)
                        {
                            fileStream.Seek(seekStart, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _lastActionResult = string.Format(ErrorMessage.FileSeekInvalidT, seekStart, fi.Length);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _lastActionResult = string.Format(ErrorMessage.FileNotFoundT, fileId);
                    Logger.Write(_lastActionResult,
                        "General", 1, Constants.LogId.RESTSync, System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Error, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                }

            }
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
          Logger.Write(ex,"General", 1, Constants.LogId.RESTSync, System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Error, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
      }

     return fileStream;

    }
```

API method on the client side project (where .svc file is):

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "files/{fileid}")]
        public Stream GetFile(string fileid)
        {
            ContentHandler handler = new ContentHandler();
            Stream fileStream = null;
            try
            {
                fileStream = handler.GetFile(fileid);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Write(string.Format("{0} {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace), "General", 1, Constants.LogId.RESTSync, System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Error, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);

                throw new WebFaultException<ErrorResponse>(new ErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message), HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }

            if (fileStream == null)
            {
                throw new WebFaultException<ErrorResponse>(new ErrorResponse(handler.LastActionResult), HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }

            return fileStream;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using REST, I presume you are using the WebHttpBinding. You need to set the MaxReceivedMessageSize on the client binding to be sufficient for the maximum expected response size. The default is 64K. [Here's the msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.webhttpbinding.maxreceivedmessagesize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the property if you are creating your binding in code. If you are creating your binding in your app.config, then [this is the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412176%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you need.